# google line chart horizontal scroll

Tags: charts, google-visualization

Is it possible (and if - what are conditions to) to scroll Google Line chart horizontally?
my attemps

```
function drawChart(param=1) {
        $.post('dactions.php',{action:'33u00',cli:<?=$cli?>,para:param},function(response){
            var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById("divChart"));
            var options={explorer: {axis: 'horizontal'},legend:'none'};
            chart.draw(new google.visualization.DataTable(response), options);
        });
```

HTML

```
<div class="nxChartsContainer" id="divChart"></div>
```

CSS

```
@media  (min-width: 1200px) {
.nxChartsContainer {width: 850px;}
}
```

ajax return good data so chart is good. but what should I do to scroll chart?

Comment: if you simply want a scrollbar, make the chart wider than the container and add css to the container --> `overflow-x: scroll;` -- but I suspect you want the y-axis to always be visible on the left, the [ChartRangeFilter](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls#chartrangefilter) is google's answer...

Comment: Yes, you are right. I want to scroll only contents of the chart (holding axis). Thanks

Comment: i also think about "pagination" of result and refresh chart any time user click "back" or "forward"